# How to automatically increase Chrome UI size?

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, display-resolution, zooming, hdpi

On my 15.6" HD laptop screen with resolution 1920 x 1080, Google Chrome looks too small by default. Not the page content but the other things like URL bar, the menu, window buttons, etc. and the font in them. The solution which I use is to add `--force-device-scale-factor=1.2` to my `google-chrome.desktop` file as shown in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1120078/728125).

Now, every time I update Chrome, the settings reset and I have to repeat the process manually. Is there some way to to do this automatically?

Comment: no, google or chromium devs would have to add an option in the browser settings this way it would be carried over. or the hacky method would be to prepare a copy of the desktop file and have a script that is run by startup applications that loops a watch on this file to see if it changed and replaces it with the backup you prepared in case it was.

Comment: @tatsu Can you please explain the hacky method? I am a complete beginner so I don't know how to write scripts. Also, what if the `.desktop` the file is has some changes after the update? My old, modified `.desktop` file won't work then.

Comment: @tatsu But I guess the `.desktop` file doesn't change very often, so I guess the hacky method will work for most of the times.

Comment: I would recommend you not let this bother you too much if you're really ill at ease with code, otherwise you can give this a read, it should be easy : https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-inotify-examples-to-replicate-directories/

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to edit not `/usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop`, but `~/.local/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop`.

Copy `/usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop` to `~/.local/share/applications` and edit it there.